# Записать формулу

Tags: python, математика

Как записать данную формулу? Смог только просто факториал написать через функцию

```
def cycle(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return(n*(cycle(n-1))) # Факториал числа
 
print(cycle(6))
```

[image]

Comment: `a = lambda n: cycle(n) / cycle(2 * n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import math
def a3(n):
    return 1/math.prod(range(n+1, 2*n+1))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def a(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    return a(n - 1) / (4 * n - 2)
```